# Conversion of special character into french special character in csv file by java code

Tags: java, localization

How to convert a special character into French language special character by java code by exporting into CSV file?

```
CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile),Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"))),',');
//CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))),',');
//CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), ',');
```

I can use these three calls but I didn't find out my output in my CSV file at the server end.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - you've currently only posted the code to create the `CsvWriter`. It's not also clear why you're using a `PrintWriter`, which may mask exceptions. Finally, I'd strongly recommend using `StandardCharsets` instead of hard-coding the names.

Comment: `ASAP`? Please post first what you have tried so far, what unexected result you got and which one do you expect.